# OpenCV different results on Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, opencv, cross-platform

I'm writing a cross-platform wrapper for OpenCV on rust. And I wrote several tests to check that my wrapper is working correctly. Some tests are passing, some tests are failing with slightly different values, but one test has completely different results.

Right number is what I get on windows, left - on linux

```
---- compare_hist_chi_square stdout ----
    thread 'compare_hist_chi_square' panicked at '2697.981816285168 == 1360.7', tests/test_imgproc.rs:81:4
---- compare_hist_bhattacharyya stdout ----
    thread 'compare_hist_bhattacharyya' panicked at '0.6798259690477988 == 0.6679', tests/test_imgproc.rs:81:4
---- compare_hist_chi_square_alternative stdout ----
    thread 'compare_hist_chi_square_alternative' panicked at '41.65613074156445 == 41.027', tests/test_imgproc.rs:81:4
---- compare_hist_correlation stdout ----
    thread 'compare_hist_correlation' panicked at '0.20456957916644988 == 0.211', tests/test_imgproc.rs:81:4
---- compare_hist_intersection stdout ----
    thread 'compare_hist_intersection' panicked at '5.440850785933435 == 5.682', tests/test_imgproc.rs:81:4
---- compare_hist_kullback_leibler_divergence stdout ----
    thread 'compare_hist_kullback_leibler_divergence' panicked at '55.71912075710992 == 54.06287', tests/test_imgproc.rs:81:4
```

I tried to reproduce code from [this article](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d8/dc8/tutorial_histogram_comparison.html). I took same images and wanted to get same results. However, it didn't happen.

Here is some Rust code that tests (just for reference):

```
extern crate cv;
extern crate float_cmp;
mod utils;

use cv::*;
use cv::imgproc::*;
use float_cmp::ApproxEqRatio;
use utils::*;

#[test]
#[should_panic]
fn compare_hist_different_dimensions_panic() {
    let first_image = load_unchanged("assets/Histogram_Comparison_Source_0.jpg");
    let second_image = load_unchanged("assets/Histogram_Comparison_Source_1.jpg");
    let _ = first_image.compare_hist(&second_image, HistogramComparisionMethod::Corellation).unwrap();
}

#[test]
fn compare_hist_correlation() {
    compare_hist(HistogramComparisionMethod::Corellation, 0.211);
}

#[test]
fn compare_hist_chi_square() {
    compare_hist(HistogramComparisionMethod::ChiSquare, 1360.7);
}

#[test]
fn compare_hist_intersection() {
    compare_hist(HistogramComparisionMethod::Intersection, 5.682);
}

#[test]
fn compare_hist_bhattacharyya() {
    compare_hist(HistogramComparisionMethod::Bhattacharyya, 0.6679);
}

#[test]
fn compare_hist_chi_square_alternative() {
    compare_hist(HistogramComparisionMethod::ChiSquareAlternative, 41.027);
}

#[test]
fn compare_hist_kullback_leibler_divergence() {
    compare_hist(
        HistogramComparisionMethod::KullbackLeiblerDivergence,
        54.06287,
    );
}

fn compare_hist(method: HistogramComparisionMethod, expected_result: f64) {
    let first_image = get_image_histogram("assets/Histogram_Comparison_Source_0.jpg");
    let second_image = get_image_histogram("assets/Histogram_Comparison_Source_1.jpg");
    let result = first_image.compare_hist(&second_image, method).unwrap();
    assert_eq(result, expected_result);
}

fn get_image_histogram(path: &'static str) -> Mat {
    let image = load_unchanged(path);
    let image = image.cvt_color(ColorConversionCodes::BGR2HSV);
    let hsize = [50, 60];
    let h_ranges = [0_f32, 180_f32];
    let s_ranges = [0_f32, 256_f32];
    let ranges = [
        h_ranges.as_ptr() as *const f32,
        s_ranges.as_ptr() as *const f32,
    ];
    let channels = [0, 1];
    let image = image.calc_hist(
        channels.as_ptr(),
        Mat::new(),
        2,
        hsize.as_ptr(),
        ranges.as_ptr(),
    );
    let image = image.normalize(0_f64, 1_f64, NormTypes::NormMinMax);
    image
}

fn assert_eq(a: f64, b: f64) {
    assert!(a.approx_eq_ratio(&b, 0.001), format!("{} == {}", a, b));
}

pub fn load_unchanged<P: AsRef<Path>>(img: P) -> Mat {
    let buf = load_image_as_buf(img);
    Mat::imdecode(&buf, ImreadModes::ImreadUnchanged)
}

fn load_image_as_buf<P: AsRef<Path>>(img: P) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut d = PathBuf::from(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"));
    d.push(img);
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    File::open(d).unwrap().read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
    buf
}
```

Probably it's because of `jpg` and different `jpg` readers on different platforms, but it can't explain `2697.98` vs `1360.7`, it's almost 2x difference!

What could be wrong here? [Here is my entire pull request](https://github.com/nebgnahz/cv-rs/pull/47) where I'm trying to add this functionality (careful, some Rust code is included)

Comment: How about converting test files to png? Do you get same results with reference code?

Comment: @VTT i'm currently trying to change `unchanged` read mode to `color`, it's closer to original test. Then I'm going to convert it to png or some loseless format like bmp, as you suggest.

Comment: png is also lossless, it is basically gzipped bitmap.

Comment: @VTT wow, i was unaware of it. Ok, i'l check it.

Comment: @VTT that's funny, but with `png` I get very close results on windows: 2902 vs 2697 on linux. However, there is still be a difference. Maybe it's because of `jpg` on linux side. Going to check it on CI, sorry, but it takes about 1 hour to build. BRB

Comment: @VTT yep, switching to lossless `png` solved the problem (I was sure it's lossy...). Please, write it as an answer, I would like to upvote it. If you didn't write it I could use `bmp` or some other crazy format that I knew is lossless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanksto @VTT, this issue happens because of different `jpg` interpretation on different platforms. Switch to `png` solves the problem